# Spring boot jsp is not rendering

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp, spring-boot

Jsp is shown as default text [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QtPo.png)

My index.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>HelloWorld</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

My index controller

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

Web Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("ru.hyndo.web")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }


    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

web app initializer

```
public class SpittrWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

}
```

RootConfig

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "ru.hyndo.web" }, excludeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = EnableWebMvc.class) })
public class RootConfig {
}
```

Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I tried everything but nothing worked. If you can give some working examples pls give.

Also if you need my project structure in idea - http://prntscr.com/iaemoc

I am stuck here and it feels like I won't ever make it :( I looked at huge amount of tutorials and as many questions on StackOverflow as I could found with no help.

Any advice is very much appreciated!

Comment: For starters for JSP to work you need a `war` not a `jar` and read [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations).

Comment: What are you seeing in the logs or console during start up?  Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: I have tried changing jar to war but im still getting the same issue

Comment: There isn't any errors in the logs

Comment: What is the WEB-INF.views in your project structure ? It should be WEB-INF/views instead

Answer (score 0):

In a **war** project, JSP pages are served from `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/`.

In a **Jar** project, JSP pages 
  **cannot**
 simply be served from webapp location or from `src/main/resources/`. That's because of the limitation stated in [boot ref docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations).

The location `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` may work in exploded form but should be avoided. From boot ref docs:

*Do not use the `src/main/webapp` directory if your application will be packaged as a **jar**. Although this directory is a common standard, it will only work with **war** packaging and it will be silently ignored by most build tools if you generate a jar.*

Fortunately there is another option for a Jar project: Servlet 3.0 specification allows to have dynamic pages in `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/` (Please check out an example [here](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/java-servlet/servlet-web-fragment/)).

[SOURCE](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/boot-serve-dynamic/)

Comment: It is web-inf/views but idea is rendering WEB-INF.views. I tried your code but it still doesn't work